# Tomcat not shutting down on windows 7

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat is not shutting down on windows 7, if we launch our servlets .

I am not able to see any threads created by our servlet or our application after shutdown but one thread with below call stack looks suspicious.

Our servlets has JNI calls.

```
ntoskrnl.exe!memset+0x61a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xd52
ntoskrnl.exe!KeRemoveQueueEx+0x323
ntoskrnl.exe!ExQueryAttributeInformation+0x17eb
ntoskrnl.exe!KeDetachProcess+0x4d2
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x3a23
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xa
ntdll.dll!RtlValidateHeap+0x3bb
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and inputs.